# Can we be sure that leptons and baryons gravitationally attract each other?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, electrons, antimatter, protons

Covid has renewed my interest in fundamental physics. But I notice that my knowledge has rusted a little bit over the years. So please bear with me.

Since unification of gravitation and quantum field theory is still an open topic, I became stuck with the following problem I found interesting:

According to the equivalence principle, inertial and gravitational mass are proportional. But, since this principle has evolved from macroscopic observations, I am not so sure whether it excludes negative gravitational masses (i.e. proportionality factor including a minus sign). More specifically, does any physical law (not just gravitation) exclude the possibility that gravitational mass and charge always have the same sign? To my knowledge, positivity of mass is always just silently introduced, without justification.

If there was no such constraint, electrons could be the sources of a negative gravitational potential (or a corresponding metric). However, since other electrons had the same signed mass, electrons would still attract each other. Similar would hold true for protons with a positive gravitational potential, but still attracting each other. The only difference, as far as I could see, would be a repulsive gravitational force between electrons and protons, which would be weak by a factor of the electron/proton mass ratio. Neutrons, if considered a compound of protons and electrons united by the process of electron capture would present a reduced gravitational potential just like a hydrogen atom would.

Astronomical objects then would be sources of a gravitational field that is reduced by ~1/2000th for the mass of the electrons contributing a negative fraction to the overall gravitational field. But, since the ratio of electrons to protons is always the same, the reduction would be everywhere the same, and hence, could be already absorbed into the gravitational constant / the proportionality of inertial and gravitational mass.

Last but not least, anti-matter would then repel ordinary matter due to the opposite charges of their baryons (I have seen a paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4937, that derives such a repulsion from assuming CPT invariance for GRT, but I guess that is a different story). There would be probably (I haven't checked) be anti-Schwarzschild solutions of the Einstein equations, and anti-Blackholes would also repel ordinary Blackholes.

Ist there any fallacy in my thinking? Or is there any experiment that can rule out the above? I guess not, since measuring the gravitational effect on electrons fails for reasons of accuracy/weakness of gravity vs. electromagnetism. But it sure would make a difference on the theory level, wouldn't it.

**Edit**: I am a bit unsure about my original (speculative) conclusion, that electrons would still attract each other, in case of their mass being negative; from the point of view of newtonian mechanics we could probably argue that a mass sign would enter quadratically into the gravitational force of like charges, resulting in an overall attractive gravitation between electrons (inertial mass must always remain positive if Lorentz' force law shall not be compromised) and a repulsive gravitation between electrons and protons; but from the point of view of GRT, the weak equivalence principle would dictate that gravitation is just geodesic motion in the external field (in this case of an electron), regardless of what kind of other charged particle falls into this field; so if electrons had negative gravitational mass, their metric and the corresponding Levi-Civita connection would be somehow inverted, but it would act the same on other electrons and protons; meaning if this metric causes repulsion, it would repel protons as well as other electrons; but then again, the question remains whether the weak equivalence principle (which has been experimentally confirmed only for makroscopic matter) could also be confirmed  for elementary particles...

Comment: The gravitational interaction of antimatter with matter or antimatter has not been conclusively observed by physicists, but it is a topic of ongoing research at CERN and other places - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_interaction_of_antimatter.

Comment: You would really break our understanding of gravity and make things much more complicated. Maybe Nature is like that, but there is no reason to think so (it is definitely not mainstream physics). Note that there are fundamental microscopic particle physics arguments to believe in the equivalence principle, for example Steven Weinberg argued that the equivalence principle follows from having unitary and Lorentz invariant scattering amplitudes involving the exchange of a massless spin-2 particle (the graviton): https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0031916364903968

Comment: @Andrew: I am afraid that the paper by Weinberg is beyond my knowledge. But what makes me careful is that he begins by arguing about properties of the graviton while I find it hard to believe that anybody knows what properties a graviton has (other than being based on a rank 2 tensor) unless gravity has been quantized successfully; and I think success probably means: in the context of the standard model

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+physics.stackexchange.com+antimatter+gravitation quite a popular theme. Could not consider it a dupe because the OP introduces specifically the interacton between the baryons and the leptons. On the other hand, if the baryons and leptons repell each other (but baryons and anti-baryons attract each other) the world could work more or less just like it does now. As far as I know, there are inconclusive results about positronium vs gravity.

Comment: @oliver The reason I brought up Weinberg's argument is since you mentioned baryons and leptons. As others have said there is a lot experimental evidence that confirms our understanding of gravity. But in order to discuss the gravitational interaction between fundamental particles one needs a gravitational force-carrier (unless the whole framework of particle physics breaks down, but that's even more complicated). We don't need a full quantum theory of gravity for Weinberg's argument to work; just basic principles of relativity and quantum mechanics applied to a massless spin-2 particle.

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/607811/) to a related question helpful.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly : of course, indirect confirmation would be okay because direct evidence for charged particles' gravity seems out of reach basically forever.

Comment: @Andrew: Weinberg's paper is also not publicly available (I am not part of a research org), but of course I could try to look up his arguments in one of my textbooks. What makes me question the merit of such effort is that the paper is from 1964 and in 2021 there is still no "quantum gravity" whatsoever. By contrast e.g., Bohr's atomic model was quickly followed up by full fledged quantum mechanics, which confirmed the usefulness of Bohr's arguments in retrospect. So then please tell me an experiment that most compellingly contradicts gravitational repulsion between electrons and the nucleus.

Comment: @A.V.S.: very interesting point. I would also not expect that such a composition effect is likely to escape discovery for at least more than one hundred years now. Which makes me believe that any difference in the "leptonic gravity" must be invariant under beta decay (and the involved quantum numbers). So it seems to me, that either the leptons gravitate like we believe today, or they do not gravitate at all, or gravity of electrons and anti-neutrinos cancel somehow (which would then probably turn to the question of anti-gravity for anti-leptons and possibly also anti-matter in general).

Comment: I think it would be very difficult to perform the required measurements due to the huge difference in strength between the gravitational and electrostatic forces between the various baryon & lepton pairs. For a pair of protons it's around $10^{39}$, so you need to measure forces with a precision of better than 39 decimals.

Comment: Here are some questions about antimatter gravity, with useful links: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/534289/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139545/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/589812/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/241060/123208

Comment: @oliver You can find versions online for free, for example Section 2.7 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.10020. But it is a quite sophisticated argument, and my reason for bringing it up is not so much to say you need to follow all the details. My main point is that there are very strong *theoretical* (in addition to observational) reasons that the equivalence principle should apply to interactions between elementary particles; what you are asking for may sound simple but actually runs *very* deeply against our understanding of gravity. (...)

Comment: (...) The argument does not rely on a full quantum theory of gravity, but rather gravity as an *effective field theory* valid at low energies, which is a well-established idea (https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9512024) that is regularly used to compute observable quantities in gravitational-wave experiments (https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.04914). My main reason to bring this up is not necessarily that you read all these papers, but to try to impress on you that people have thought deeply about this before and what you are asking for is very hard to fit in with everything else we know about physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can be sure that leptons and baryons attract each other. Eotvos experiments and other tests of the equivalence principle give null results to about one part in $10^{11}$ these days. Under your hypothesis, different chemical substances would have different gravitational accelerations, and therefore we would get violations on the order of one part in $10^4$.

Comment: In my original argument ("neutron = proton+electron+anti-neutrino") I have totally overlooked the binding energy 0.78 MeV, which is already of the order $10^{-4}$. So even if the (hypothetically anti-gravitating) electrons would partly cancel the gravitational mass of protons in the same way as the gravitational neutron mass would be reduced (internally), there would still be a remaining chemical composition effect due to the binding energy 0.78 MeV captured inside the neutron.

Comment: So the ratio between gravitational and inertial mass would have to be different for hydrogen and a neutron for example, due to the binding energy of the neutron entering the ratio always positively. So I am finally convinced that the validity of the equivalence principle is strong evidence against lepton anti-gravity.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing that came to my mind once I had swallowed the equivalence principle / chemical composition explanation, is the following:

If leptons were repelled in the gravitational field of baryons, an electron as part of a hydrogen atom would also be repelled in the external gravitational field of the earth (which is dominated by the mass of the baryons), whereas the proton of this hydrogen atom would be attracted by the earth. Something similar would happen if leptons did not participate in gravitation at all.

But then, the hydrogen atom would show a permanent electric dipole moment in the gravitational field, which would be very easily detectable, but has never been.